# How to send images via socket server? (Not TCPClient)

Tags: c#, image, sockets

I have a problem with sending or receiving image (I don't know which part fails because my image is getting cutted on receive). I know that this kind of problem has much posts about it but any of these wasn't working for me.

So simply I have "my" **socket server** (not TCPClient). Server have to get screenshot of screen and send it to the client.

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
   Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
   int received;
   IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = current.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
   try
   {
       received = current.EndReceive(AR);
   }
   catch (SocketException)
   { 
       current.Close();
       return;
   }

   byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
   Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
   string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
   Console.Write("Received Text: ");
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
   Console.WriteLine(text);

   if(text.ToLower() == "screenshot")
   { 
        Image a = get_image.doscreen();
        current.Send(ImageToByte(a));
   }
   if(current.Connected)
        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
}
```

I know that's not much code to show but I've done this server from tutorial and whole code it's pretty basic. Also I know that it might be buffer problem but I don't know how to fix this.

"My" **client** code:

```
private static void send()
{
    try
    {
        string req = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
        _clientsocket.Send(buffer);

        byte[] receivedbuf = new byte[1024];
        int rec = _clientsocket.Receive(receivedbuf, receivedbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        byte[] data = new byte[rec];
        Array.Copy(receivedbuf, data, rec);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));


        if (req.ToLower() == "screenshot")
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes("test.png", data);
        }
  }
  catch(Exception){
  }
}
```

Comment: prolly you should define some protocol ... you assume that you will get same count of "read" as you use "write" ... but it's not true

Comment: what do you mean with "define some protocol"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol